# JQuery temporary disable animation when performing another

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

How to temporary disable animation ?

I have a `.move_box` and when you click on it, it will expand. On that `.move_box` there is a **X** that closes the box ( same animation only reverse parameters).

The problem is when you click on that **X** it will close the box and perform the opening animation again because the **X** is on the `.move_box` that triggers the first animation.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box move_box">
    <div class="box_title">
        <label>BODY CONDITION</label><h6 class="exit">X</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="box_image">
        <img src="http://ferringtonpost.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Responsibilities-of-Owning-a-New-Puppy-Photo-by-bestdogsforkids.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.move_box').click(function(){
        $(this).find('.exit').show();
        $(this).css({"z-index":"20"});
        $(this).animate({"height": "529px", "width": "460px"}, "slow");
        $(this).find('img').animate({"width": "460px"}, "slow");
    });

    $('.exit').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('img').animate({"width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SK37k/).

How to fix it ?

Comment: Bind to .exit first and use return false at the end of it's handler, that way when exit is clicked, the move_box element doesn't receive the event.

Comment: There is some thing we call, stop animation use that.
$("#stop").click(function(){
  $("#panel").stop();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the X element is inside the .movie_box div, when you click the X element the event is propagated to its parent's elements. You have to stop it.

Add a parameter to the click function on .exit and call the method stopPropagation

```
$('.exit').click(function(e){
        $(this).parent().parent().find('img').animate({"width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).parent().parent().animate({"height": "163px", "width": "220px"}, "slow");
        $(this).hide();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.move_box').click(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('exit')) {
        // the exit button was clicked, thus escape this handler
        return;
    }
```